# Could anyone help me with this python singpath program?

Tags: python, stack, postfix-notation

First of all, this is not for any class.
I have been working on these 2 programs for a long time and cannot make heads or tails of it. I really want to get past these problems so I can move onto other lessons.
"Create a function that transforms the prefix notation into postfix notation, and postfix notation into prefix notation. The function takes two arguments. The first is a string of an expression without spaces or syntax errors, and the second is another string contains all the operators. Characters not in the second string are regarded as operands. The lengths of all the operators and operands are 1, and all the operators are binary operators."
ex:

```
>>> fix_trans('ab33c2c11','abc')
'33b211cca'
```

and Convert to (reverse) Polish notation:

```
>>> toPolish('(3+5)*(7-2)',D,0)
'*+35-72'
```

Comment: Can we see what you've tried?

Comment: In your "toPolish" function, what do the `D` and `0` arguments do?

Comment: The second is a dictionary, the keys and the values of which are the operators and the priority of the operators, the larger taking precedence over the smaller. The third is a boolean value to determine whether the Polish notation is reverse (if not true it is reverse Polish).

Comment: I have gotten to where I separated the operators and the numbers, but besides that, I can't figure out any kind of algorithm to keep the numbers in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any examples of how far you've gotten with this, or what methods haven't worked for you? Also, are you familiar with the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)?

Comment: I have been able to implement a function to evaluate the reverse polish and polish notations with no problem, but changing one into another is where I get stuck. I am able to recognize when it is pre and postfix and then pass those to separate functions but all my attempts to define the functions failed